# Share a transaction between Java and Groovy via Spring/Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, groovy, transactions

I have succesfully create some Groovy beans inside my Java Spring application. With suprise, I noted that even @Autowired worked from Groovy code to Java, so I am getting the best from both worlds.

I have noted that in Groovy there is a single object, SQL, to commuinicate with DB.

I have instructed my code to work like this: a Java service (marked @transactional) that will call a Java DAO, then a Groovy class. In the groovy class I want to read data updated in the DAO.

In my tests, however, groovy-SQL is not getting reference to the transaction, so the results are never correct.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the same transaction in both classes ?

Comment: 1. How does your Groove class obtain the db connection? 2. Post the relevant code, otherwise it is impossible to give any exact answer.

Comment: Just curious, why not using same repo/DAO in groovy ?

Comment: Hey guys, I eventually solved this problem (by using Spring transctions in groovy), buy since then I changed job so I cannot find the relevant code AND the relevant solution. I should close this question